# Render pygal charts without borders

Tags: python, charts, pygal

I am looking for the way of rendering charts without borders using [pygal](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/index.html). I have no found anything useful in the documentation. However, I have identified a very strange situation looking the examples. Lets see:

[image: Chart with no border in the y-axis]

In this example, you can see that **the chart has no frame in the y-axi**, but there is not a specific statement to achieve this. Now take a look at this other example:

[image]

In this case, the example shows how truncate the labels of the x-axis, but for some reason **there is a border in the y-axi**, and again there is not a specific statement.

What is happening? How could I deal with it? I would need to know the way for rendering the chart without any border, does anyone know something about it?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code for graph/graph.py the y axis is only printed out if there are x_labels.

By borders in the chart it seems like you are referring to gridlines. So if you would like to remove them in the line chart you are building you can add two functions to the Line class in graph/line.py or any other chart type that you would like to remove them from.

Just put in a new CustomLine class where you're building your application like below:

```
import pygal


class CustomLine(pygal.Line):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _x_axis(self):
        pass

    def _y_axis(self):
        pass


chart = CustomLine()
chart.add('Series 1', [0, 0.005, 0.002])
chart.render_response()
```

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It was useful because now I can disable the left gridline, but my next question is: is there a way for disabling the y-axi without disabling the x-axi?

Comment: Assuming that you want to include x_labels in to Pygal then the answer is no. You could however alter the code a little in your graph/graph.py.

The Y-axis is created in the _x_axis function and when self.x_labels in True. You could comment out this part on line 163:

    self.svg.node(
                guides, 'path',
                d='M%f %f v%f' % (x or 0, 0, self.view.height),
                class_='%sline' % 'guide ')

Comment: Thank you so much !! It was really useful